# How to use an enumeration with a class and an overloaded << operator in C++ 11 or later?

Tags: c++, class, enums, overloading

I'm learning C++ and this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum class Genre {
    unknown, fiction, nonfiction, periodical, biography, children
};

class Book {
    public:
        Genre getGenre() {return gen;}
        void setGenre(Genre gBook) {gen=gBook;}
private:
    Genre gen;
};

vector<Book> books;

void readInBooks() {        // loop a few times to get some elements in books
    int genre;
    cout << "Please enter genre (1 fiction, 2 nonfiction, 3 periodical, 4 biography, 5 children): ";
    cin >> genre;
    Book b;
    Genre g=Genre(genre);
    b.setGenre(g);
    books.push_back(b);
}

void printBooks() {
    cout << "Total library:" << endl << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<books.size();i++) {
        cout << "Book " << i << ": " << books[i].getGenre() << endl;          
    }
}

int main() {
    readInBooks();
    printBooks();
    return 0;
}
```

So the line:

```
 cout << "Book " << i << ": " << books[i].getGenre() << endl;
```

gives this error:

no match for operator<< operand types are basic_ostream and Genre.

So I tried:

```
 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre& g) {
    os << g.getGenre();
    return os;
 }
```

in the public part of class Book and got error:

request for member getGenre in g, which is of non-class type Genre.

Thank you for explaining me what I do wrong.

Comment: You confused `Book` and `Genre`. `Book`s have a member function `.getGenre` but `Genre` doesn't.

Comment: you implementation of `ostream << Genre` would result in an infinite loop if it was correct otherwise, because `os << g.getGenre();` willl call itself again. In general you need to implement `ostream<<` in terms of already existing overloads

Comment: Do you want to show the Genre as int or as string?

Answer (score 3):

Your operator is related to enum - it has nothing to do with Book and should not be in any way related to Book class

So after defining the enum you can define the operator for printing it

```
enum class Genre {
    unknown, fiction, nonfiction, periodical, biography, children
};
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Genre& g)
{
    switch (g) {
    case Genre::unknown:
        return os << "unknown";
    case Genre::fiction:
        return os << "fiction";
    case Genre::nonfiction:
        return os << "nonfiction";
    case Genre::periodical:
        return os << "periodical";
    case Genre::biography:
        return os << "biography";
    case Genre::children:
        return os << "children";
    }
    return os << static_cast<int>(g); //this line should be unreachable
    // - but for future extention of enum if you forget to extend the switch as well
    //I have added a protection
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In :

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre& g) {
    os << g.getGenre();
    return os;
 }
```

g is of type Genre and have no methode getGenre. getGenre is a method of type book.

You can try this :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre& g) {

    if( g == Genre::unknown)
        os << "unknown";
    else if( g == Genre::fiction)
        os << "fiction";
    else if( g == Genre::nonfiction)
        os << "nonfiction";
    else if( g == Genre::periodical)
        os << "periodical";
    else if( g == Genre::biography)
        os << "biography";
    else if( g == Genre::children)
        os << "children";
    else
        os << "unknow_genre";
    return os;
 }
```

or this :

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre& g) {

    os << (int)g;
    return os;
 }
```

Comment: If you want to print the names of the enum values, you should use a `switch` instead of a series of `if`s.  Or, use a `std::map<Genre, std::string>`.  Or, even just a static `const char*[]` array that is indexed by `Genre` values.

Comment: Or use `if` because i like this way to do thing

Answer (score 0):

When you call `<< books[i].getGenre()`, you are passing a `Genre` to `operator<<`, not a `Book`.  So, you are on the right track to define a custom `operator<<` for `Genre`.  However, your implementation is wrong, because `Genre` does not have a `getGenre()` method.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum class Genre {
    unknown, fiction, nonfiction, periodical, biography, children
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre g) {
    switch (g) {
        case Genre::fiction:
            os << "fiction"; break;
        case Genre::nonfiction:
            os << "nonfiction"; break;
        case Genre::periodical:
            os << "periodical"; break;
        case Genre::biography:
            os << "biography"; break;
        case Genre::children:
            os << "children"; break;
        default:
            os << "unknown"; break;
    }
    return os;
} 

/* alternatively:

static const char* GenreNames[] = {
    "unknown", "fiction", "nonfiction", "periodical", "biography", "children"
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre g) {
    os << GenreNames[static_cast<int>(g)];
    return os;
}
*/

class Book {
    public:
        Genre getGenre() { return gen; }
        void setGenre(Genre gBook) { gen = gBook; }
    private:
        Genre gen;
};

vector<Book> books;

void readInBooks() {
    int genre;
    // loop to get some elements in books
    do {
        do {
            cout << "Please enter genre (0 done, 1 fiction, 2 nonfiction, 3 periodical, 4 biography, 5 children): ";
            cin >> genre;
            if (genre == 0) return;
            if ((genre >= 1) && (genre <= 5)) break;
            cout << "Invalid choice!" << endl;
        }
        while (true);

        Book b;
        b.setGenre(static_cast<Genre>(genre));
        books.push_back(b);
    }
    while (true);
}

void printBooks() {
    cout << "Total library:" << endl << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Book " << i << ": " << books[i].getGenre() << endl;          
    }
}

int main() {
    readInBooks();
    printBooks();
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, consider implementing an `operator<<` for `Book` as well, especially if you plan on adding more details to it later on (title, author, etc):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

enum class Genre {
    unknown, fiction, nonfiction, periodical, biography, children
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre g) {
    switch (g) {
        case Genre::fiction:
            os << "fiction"; break;
        case Genre::nonfiction:
            os << "nonfiction"; break;
        case Genre::periodical:
            os << "periodical"; break;
        case Genre::biography:
            os << "biography"; break;
        case Genre::children:
            os << "children"; break;
        default:
            os << "unknown"; break;
    }
    return os;
} 

/* alternatively:

static const char* GenreNames[] = {
    "unknown", "fiction", "nonfiction", "periodical", "biography", "children"
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Genre g) {
    os << GenreNames[static_cast<int>(g)];
    return os;
}
*/

class Book {
    public:
        Genre getGenre() const { return gen; }
        void setGenre(Genre gBook) { gen = gBook; }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Book &b) {
            os << b.getGenre();
            // output other details as needed...
            return os;
        } 

    private:
        Genre gen;
};

vector<Book> books;

void readInBooks() {
    int genre;
    // loop to get some elements in books
    do {
        do {
            cout << "Please enter genre (0 done, 1 fiction, 2 nonfiction, 3 periodical, 4 biography, 5 children): ";
            cin >> genre;
            if (genre == 0) return;
            if ((genre >= 1) && (genre <= 5)) break;
            cout << "Invalid choice!" << endl;
        }
        while (true);

        Book b;
        b.setGenre(static_cast<Genre>(genre));
        books.push_back(b);
    }
    while (true);
}

void printBooks() {
    cout << "Total library:" << endl << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < books.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Book " << i << ": " << books[i] << endl;          
    }
}

int main() {
    readInBooks();
    printBooks();
    return 0;
}
```